# Piping https proxy request over socket connection to named pipe (node.js)

Tags: node.js, sockets, https, proxy, named-pipes

I'm trying to build a forward proxy server which can take a request for an http url and pipe that request to an https server listening on a named pipe.

I know I'm missing a step but I'm not sure what it is. This is what I'm trying to use...

```
function pipeToServer(browserRequest, browserSocket, browserRequestHead){

    var targetUrl = url.parse('https://' + browserRequest.url);
    var namedPipe = getNamedPipe()

    console.log("Attempting to connect to " + namedPipe)
    var proxySocket = net.connect(namedPipe, function() {
        console.log("Connected to destination server: " + namedPipe)
        console.log("Sending head: " + browserRequestHead)
        browserSocket.write('HTTP/' + browserRequest.httpVersion + ' 200 Connection Established\r\n' +'Proxy-agent: Node-Proxy\r\n' + '\r\n');
        proxySocket.write(browserRequestHead);
        proxySocket.pipe(browserSocket);
        browserSocket.pipe(proxySocket);
    });
}
```

The connection is successful but the request handler for the target server (listening on the named pipe) is never fired. Interestingly the browserRequestHead always seems to blank too.

I'm lost. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The code posted in the original question turned out ot be working fine. The problem was related to the ssl certificates being used. The request wasn't making it through to the destination server because the TLS handshake was failing.